# Change default_character_set while connected to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to change the `--default-character-set` to `utf8` while connected to MySQL (meaning in the `mysql>` shell) for a particular database? I tried something like:

```
mysql> --default-character-set=utf8 database_name
```

But that doesn't work.

Any help please

Comment: Did you try `SET NAMES utf8;`?

Comment: does that do the same thing as `--default-character-set=utf8`?

Comment: It will ensure that data transfers across the current connection are utf8. But you also need to ensure that your tables/databases are utf8 as well.

Answer (score 1):

In the */config/database.properties* add the characterEncoding:

```
connectionProperties.characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Or in shell this [link](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD3/Configuring+UTF8+Character+Set+for+MySQL) is very useful.